Home position of a wind turbine
I've recently seen a still standing wind turbine which appeared to be in "home position", that is, one wing going straight to the top and the other two going down at 60°:

Intuitively, this position seems like the most energy-efficient position for a still wind turbine to rest in (given that there is no wind or any other influences except gravity).
But the potential energy of a still wind turbine is always constant, no matter how the wings are rotated: the average of the heights of the tips of the wings is always the height of the center - this follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4384518/221738.
So is my intuition wrong, or is there something I have not considered when calculating the potential energy?

If a wind turbine had a "preferred" (least potential energy) resting position then its centre of mass would not be on its axis of rotation i.e. it would be unbalanced. But an unbalanced wind turbine would quickly shake itself apart when moving - even the much smaller propeller on a small boat causes noticeable vibrations if it is unbalanced.

If the blades were properly balanced and equal in mass, there should be no preferred resting position. By symmetry, the centre of mass of a three bladed propeller or turbine will be at the axis of rotation. What I mean by this is the following:

Suppose the centre of mass is not at the axis.

Then, since there is three-fold rotational symmetry, there are three equally valid places that the centre of mass should be.

It follows that the assumption in (1.) cannot be correct.


Therefore, the statement

Intuitively, this position seems like the most energy-efficient position for a still wind turbine to rest in

is not correct.
Also, the kinetic energy of a stationary turbine should be zero. So therefore I think you mean to say potential energy.
Nevertheless, the potential energy of the propeller should be the same in any position if everything is balanced properly.

You're right, I meant potential energy, thanks. And yes, your reasoning is the one described in the math-MO-answer. So now I'm wondering why my intuition was incorrect...

Is your intuition coming from the fact that in the picture you posted, there is more mass below than above the axis? If this is the case, it might help to imagine the two lower blades as a single concentrated mass at a point closer to the axis (because they are angled)

Yes, I think that’s where the Intuition comes from.
